# Tensions in the chains

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

[image]

What is the physics behind this mechanism? What would be the free body diagram be like regarding all the magnitudes of the tension forces present in the chains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple. As can be seen in the photo, there is no tension in the chains on the left because they are visibly slack. There is some tension in the chains on the right, but this is only because the person standing on the platform is not perfectly centered and balanced. If he was, there would be no tension in the side chains, and all the weight of the person is supported by tension in the chain at the centre. The four corner chains are there to prevent the top tilting or twisting.

Edit: Thanks for the upvotes and correct answer tick, but I do not feel I did this answer justice, as I ducked the issue of what the tension in the side chains would be if the person is standing off centre.

Let's say the person is standing on a diagonal (a distance $D_A$ from the centre), such that a single corner chain (a distance $D_B$ from the centre) has to provide all the balancing tension.

[image]

If the weight of the person provides a downforce of $F_A $ newtons, this would produce a torque of $T_A = F_A D_A$. The corner chain produces a balancing torque of $T_B = F_B D_B$. This resolves to $F_B = F_A \times D_A / D_B$.

The vertical forces have to balance too, so we have:

$F_C = -(F_A + F_B) = -F_A (1 + D_A / D_B)$.

This is the upward force exerted by the chain in the centre.

For a simple numerical example, if the person standing on a corner of the platform (so that $D_A = D_B$) and is exerting a force of $800$ N, then the balancing tension of the chain on the opposite corner is also $800$ N. The upward tension force exerted by the chain in the middle is $F_C = -F_A (1 + D_A / D_B) = -1600 $ N, which is twice the force exerted by the centre chain when the person is standing exactly in the centre. This may be important if you actually build such a table, as the centre chain has to be able to cope with additional force if the supported weight is off centre.

P.S. I assumed the fulcrum is above the chain in the centre for simplicity, but it can be placed anywhere, and the end results come out the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here a 2D moodel and the internal actions

[image]

And here some details of the computations

[image]