# Tensions in the chains

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

[image]

What is the physics behind this mechanism? What would be the free body diagram be like regarding all the magnitudes of the tension forces present in the chains?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/800794/2451