# How can the force acting at the fulcrum of a lever be calculated?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

I know how to calculate the force applied to either or both ends of a lever system, but I would like to know how to calculate the force applied over the fulcrum of a lever.

Comment: Hi Olivia. Welcome to PF. My answer to the "Tension in the chains" question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/800794/tensions-in-the-chains/800800#800800 gives a nice worked example of calculating the force on the fulcrum of a pivot. It might help your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pivot where the arm on the left has a length of 2 m and the arm on the right has a length of 8 m. We can balance the torques by placing weights on the ends, such that the force on the left arm is 8 N and the force on the right arm is 2 N, so that the clockwise torque is 16 Nm balanced by an anticlockwise torque of 16 Nm.

To find the force that is acting on the fulcrum, the secret is to realise that when everything is in equilibrium, so that nothing is moving, we also have to balance the vertical forces. The total force downwards is 8 N on the left and 2 N on the right, giving a total of 10 N acting on the fulcrum. This has to be balanced by an equal force acting upwards at the fulcrum.

Since torque is force $\times$ distance from the pivot, the torque at the pivot is zero, but there is a non-zero downwards linear force equal to the sum of all the forces acting downward.

It's interesting to note that when calculating the total torque acting on an object, that we don't have to pick the fulcrum as the pivot point for the calculations. For example, I could pick the far left end as the pivot point. The torque acting there would now be zero. The torque at the far right would be 2 N $\times$ 10 m = 20 Nm clockwise. Remember the reaction force of 10 N acting upwards at the fulcrum? That is now producing an anticlockwise torque of 10 N $\times$ 2 m = 20 Nm. Everything still balances.

The difference between a pivot point and a fulcrum is that a pivot point is the point that is considered to be the centre of rotation for calculations, while the fulcrum supports the weight of the lever and can also be the pivot point.